# Pandas - List most common value in column with most common sub-values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame where it lists a number of values in column A, which also have different values assigned in columns B and C.

I am trying to use pandas to extract the most frequent value (i) in Column A, and then print the n most frequent values assigned to i in column B and C.

The code I have is as follows:

```
d = df[['CA', 'CB', 'CC']]
d.sort_values('CA')
print("CA:", d.CA.mode(), d.CB.mode(), d.CC.mode())
```

but this is not working.

Also, I just want the field names. When I print to STDOUT it also includes the dtype, which I do not need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are these columns strings? `df['CA'].describe()['top']` will provide the top value if that column is a string. if not, you can make it a string: `df['CA'].astype(str).describe()['top']`

Comment: Can you update your question and give an example of your **df**